# SessionID is same but session data are not same

Tags: asp.net, .net, session

I created two different very simple apps (ASP .NET) and host on the local iis. 
Both apps are open in same browser in two tabs. In first application (AppA) I store some data in Session (Session["name"] = "john") and in second application (AppB) I read this value. When I explore cookies (with FireCookie) I saw that SessionIDs for both applications are same. Also, In both apps SessionID is printed and are the same. When I try get this value in AppB from session (with correct key), session is empty, but session id is still same. In AppA session data are still alive.

Why session data are different when both apps ask web server (with same session id) to return data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sessions are not shared, because it are different applications. So even when they got the same id, they don't "know" eachother. Check out this article for a possible solution http://www.codeguru.com/article.php/c19357

Comment: Ok. Look at this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net
in paragraph Session ID. He says:... When the client requests for data, ASP.NET looks for the session ID and retrieves the corresponding data....

Comment: @SilverDeveloper: they key thing is that the two applications have completely different session stores. With certain session providers you may be able to do this (eg if they were both SQL based or something) but in general it is effectively keying the session data on application and sessionID.

Comment: maybe storing the Sessions in a database is an idea in this case?

Comment: @Chris - If both apps have same SessioID, and after postback, how server knows which is which?

Comment: @SilverDeveloper: the code always runs in the context of an app. It knows which app it is in the same way it knows what web.config it should be using. You set the apps up in IIS separately and they run separately. They may not even be in the same app pool.